# How can I put Log in controller in laravel project?

Tags: php, laravel

I am looking for a way to put logs in Laravel's controller function.
Where Should I put Log functions? Where Can I find the log? 
There are any logs in {Project_name}/storage/logs/laravel.log 
I would like to put a logging to check if the request values are all correct.

the setting of .env seems to be APP_DEBUG=true

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Article;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class StackOvefFloeController extends Controller
{

    public function store(ScheduleRequest $request)
    {
        $schedules = DB::table('schedules')->get();

        $request->date;
        $request->hours;
        //Where Should I put Log functions? Where Can I find the log?

        Log::info('start hpirs'. $request->hours);
        dd($request->start_hours);
        error_log('start hpirs'. $request->start_hours);

        return view('debug', ['schedules' => $schedules]);
    }
```

```
<div class = "test">
    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('debug.store') }}">
      @csrf
        <input type="checkbox" class="date"" name="available_date" value="2015-05-22">
        <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="hours" value="8">8
        <button type ="submit">SEND</button></form>
</div>
```

Comment: It's ok, if you set `Log::info('start hpirs: '. $request->hours);` in your controller, the logs will be on `{Project_name}/storage/logs/laravel.log` file

Comment: I've noticed that the page doesn't link to ''debug". After clicking "SEND" button, my browser reloads the page.I mean, it doesn't seem to call store function.

Answer (score 0):

this way correct : Log::info('message');

you can set log file from .env file every day set with this code : APP_LOG=daily